# Cant run flutter because of gradle issues cp_proj generic class cache

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

So here is the error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not open cp_proj generic class cache for build file 'C:\Users\teris\test\android\build.gradle' (C:\Users\teris.gradle\caches\7.5\scripts\21cu7jrt5s4ct65acfwhlwy69).
> BUG! exception in phase 'conversion' in source unit '*BuildScript*' class org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.TupleExpression cannot be cast to class org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression (org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.TupleExpression and org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression are in unnamed module of loader org.gradle.internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader @1c4af82c)

I am using JDK18 and gradle 7.5, i cleared cache,

here is my android\build.gradle:

```
`buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

plugins {
  // ...

  // Add the dependency for the Google services Gradle plugin
  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}`
```

here is my app\build.gradle:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}



def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    namespace "com.example.test"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.test"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

plugins {
  id 'com.android.application'

  // Add the Google services Gradle plugin
  id 'com.google.gms.google-services'

  ...
}

dependencies {
  // Import the Firebase BoM
  implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.1.1')


  // TODO: Add the dependencies for Firebase products you want to use
  // When using the BoM, don't specify versions in Firebase dependencies
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'


  // Add the dependencies for any other desired Firebase products
  // https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available-libraries
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

thanks for trying to help, if something is unsure, let me know

As i said i tried to change to JDK version, a tried to clear the caches, but nothing helps. Any ideas are welcomed, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so after some more digging i find the solution! So here it is for anyone with the same issues.

https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/7897

i had my plugins in the /android build and not in the /app build, after aplying this solution from github and changing the hub, i experienced some more errors, but resolved them easily, goodluck for anyone with the same issues :D